# No cache data for this platform

Tags: sgx

I have installed pccs on my vm with sgx enabled, the I run sudo systemctl start pccs and `curl -k -G "https://localhost:8081/sgx/certification/v4/rootcacrl"` but I get error `No cache data for this platform`.
my kernel is :

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-1029-azure (buildd@lcy02-amd64-076) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 6 17:00:26 UTC 2022
```

this is the pccs_server.log:

```
2022-12-27 16:25:22.885 [info]: HTTPS Server is running on: https://localhost:8081
2022-12-27 16:26:17.206 [info]: Client Request-ID : 19de7dcf832143418bd560e236a3e745
2022-12-27 16:26:17.210 [error]: Error: No cache data for this platform.
    at ReqCachingMode.getRootCACrlFromPCS (file:///opt/intel/sgx-dcap-pccs/services/caching_modes/cachingMode.js:84:11)
    at CachingModeManager.getRootCACrlFromPCS (file:///opt/intel/sgx-dcap-pccs/services/caching_modes/cachingModeManager.js:73:23)
    at Module.getRootCaCrl (file:///opt/intel/sgx-dcap-pccs/services/rootcacrlService.js:47:36)
    at async getRootCaCrl (file:///opt/intel/sgx-dcap-pccs/controllers/rootcacrlController.js:38:21)
2022-12-27 16:26:17.217 [info]: 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2022:16:26:17 +0000] "GET /sgx/certification/v4/rootcacrl HTTP/1.1" 404 32 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

does any body knows the issue?